# Video Processing OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv, hsv

I am trying to pass in a HSV frame from a video to the function, but the function does not seem to do anything to it. What am I doing wrong? The function is supposed to go through each pixel, and depending on its hue range supposed to make it black or white, leaving me with a binary image. Instead it doesn't seem to affect the HSV image at all....

Thanks 
PS sorry for the bad code formatting, StackOverflow isn't allowing me to post the original format.

```
void sort (IplImage *skinmask)
{
  for (int row=0; row<=skinmask->height;row++)
  {
    uchar* pixelrow=(uchar*)(skinmask->imageData+(row*(skinmask->widthStep)));
    for (int column=0; column<=skinmask->width; column++)
    {
        if (6<pixelrow[3*column]<36)
        {
            pixelrow[3*column]=256;
            pixelrow[(3*column)+1]=256;
            pixelrow[(3*column)+2]=256;
        }
        else
        {
            pixelrow[3*column]=0;
            pixelrow[(3*column)+1]=0;
            pixelrow[(3*column)+2]=0;
        }
        column++;
    }
    row++;
  }
  cvMorphologyEx(skinmask,skinmask,NULL,NULL,CV_MOP_CLOSE,1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing an operation like thresholding pixel-by-pixel is usually the wrong way to go about achieving this in OpenCV - there are functions that work on whole image arrays that are simpler and are already optimized for speed.

In this case try first [splitting](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-split) the image to separate out the H/S/V channels, then [threshold](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-threshold) on the Hue channel to get a mask (you may have to use the intersection of two masks, which you can do using a multiply or "bitwise and") - the resulting mask is your black and white image.

(I realise I've linked to the C++ documentation, but I'm sure you can find the equivalent functions in the old-style OpenCV docs)

### Update

Ok, I'll try to write some code to show what I mean.  I also found the function I was looking for, which is better than Threshold, it is [InRangeS](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#inranges).  This lets you put upper and lower bounds on all the channels at once, and it applies them all into your mask for you.

```
void HSVImageToMask(IplImage * image, cvMat * mask)
/* mask should be the same size as image, and of type CV_8UC1            */
/* e.g. cvMat * mask = cvCreateMat(image->width, image->height, CV8UC1); */
{
  double hMin = 6;
  double hMax = 36;
  double sMin = 10;  /* not sure what value you need */
  double sMax = 245; /* not sure what value you need */
  double vMin = 0;
  double vMax = 255;

  CvScalar hsvMin = cvScalar(hMin, sMin, vMin);
  CvScalar hsvMax = cvScalar(hMax, sMax, vMax);

  cvInRangeS(image, hsvMin, hsvMax, mask);
}
```

PS. I figured out the problem with your original code - you should be using 255 instead of 256 as your "white" value.  This method is still better though :)

PPS. We didn't need them after all but for future reference:

["bitwise and"](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#and):

```
cvAnd(const CvArr* src1, const CvArr* src2, CvArr* dst)
```

If you have two black and white masks, this will give you the intersection.  Use cvOr to get the Union.

Comment: If your method would result in a really big improvement could you please expand on how I would do that? If I split up the channels and do a threshold, how would I do the multiply or bitwise and? I have no idea what a bitwise and is or how to multiply images. 

Oh and also it turns, I need to check values in saturation too, so how would I do this too?

Thanks :)

Comment: Great example; thanks brian.  Didn't know about cvInRangeS either.